# how to add python in xilinx vitis

Tags: python, fpga, xilinx

I have implemented a Zynq ZCU102 board in vivado and I want to use final ".XSA" file into VITIS, but after creating a new platform, its languages are C and C++, While in the documentation was told that vitis supports python.
My question is how can I add python to my vitis platform?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to the documentation section you are mentioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Python in FPGA needs an Operating System. I had to run Linux OS on my FPGA using petaLinux and then run python code on it.

Answer (score 1):

The AMD ZCU102 Evaluation Kit is based on the AMD Zynq UltraScale+ XCZU9EG-2FFVB1156 MPSoC. This is not a pure FPGA, but an SoC (System-on-Chip) based on a dual-core ARM® Cortex®-A9 processor (referred to as the *Processing System* or **PS**), integrated with an FPGA fabric (referred to as *Programmable Logic* or **PL**).

Actually you cannot execute a Python interpreter on the PL, but on an OS running on the PS.

You can use the Petalinux SDK (see [PetaLinux Tools Documentation: Reference Guide (UG1144)](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide)) to build Linux for the PS on the Zynq Ultrascale+, along with the required BSP for the ZCU102 board ([Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC Board Support Packages](https://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/embedded-design-tools.html)).

If you include Python in the Linux RootFS, you can finally run Python code on the ZCU102.